# How EF generate insertion SQL for entity class that has default 0?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework, just a question on how EF generate insertion SQL for entity class that has default 0.

This is the data model class:

```
public class Product
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the underlying table Products in Sql server has identity column on ProductID .

So let's say a controller that use model binding to create a Product object p1, and then we do:

```
context.Products.Add(p1)   //p1.ProductID = 0 for default
context.SaveChanges();
```

My questions are:

1. Does EF need to send a query to database to get latest primary key in `Products` table and then plus 1 to be `p1.ProductID`? Isn't that very inefficient as you need to query database for latest existing primary key and then send another insert SQL to insert record?
2. what does the `Dbset<Product>.add()` method really mean? I mean if the object's id is 0, we know it doesn't exist in the database (if id > 0 then we know we are modifying existing record), can't we just add newly created p1 to the database, why we still need to track it?

Comment: You can use sql-profiler to monitor sql-queries generated by EF

Comment: **Either** you define the primary key to be an `IDENTITY` column in the database (preferred option) - then your SQL Server will take care of handing out a new, unique key value - or else **you** have to provide a value and make sure it's unique. EF will certainly **NOT** do a  `SELECT MAX(col)+1` approach ......

Comment: @marc_s  yes the Products table has IDENTITY column on ProductID in sql server. But how can EF know this fact? and maybe there are other identify columns in the table, that's why I think EF has to do sth like send a query to Sql server in order to 'know' which columns are identity columns?

Comment: By adding the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation to your key column .... as simple as that ....

Answer (score 0):

1.) no, you dont need to get latest object's primary key to determine next Id.

2.) `Primary Key starts from 1 not 0`,in EF if you use default identity provider as explained below, EF can manage Primary Key auto, so no need to set `ANY` number to that variable. Then, `context.Products.Add(p1)` adds value to Local Table (in RAM), after addition `context.SaveChanges();` will trigger to send Local Values to SQL Database.`After SaveChanges you will see correct Id of value`

there is a feature to generate auto Id for tables.

- firstly, you should select which property is Primary Key with `[Key]` attribute.
- Secondly, you should determine the type of Primary Key whether Integer or String (`string has no auto Id Generator`)
- Then, if it is Integer and you need auto Id generator, you should use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to auto generator.
- After that, you dont worry about value of `ProductID` EF can manage it.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

not: if you want string Primary Key (or manually add Id) you should use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

[more examples about EF](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/databasegenerated-dataannotations-attribute.aspx) (select EF version from navigator)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. for q2, the definition of Add() says it has sth to do with tracking, but since p1 is created py model binding, which means it is newly created record and has to be inserted into database anywhere, so why p1 still needs to be tracked?

Comment: until using SaveChanges your object is not at db but tracking on localServer, it is acting like at db before using savechanges, so you can still reference that object, but be sure there is no conflicts to block successfully doing savechanges. otherwise you will get null reference error because object won't be at db